# how to convert datetime in format 23:59:59

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date, datetime

I'm having two dates `FromDate` and `toDate`

converting dates like following and passing as parameters to stored procedure:

both variable are of DateTime FromDate, DateTime toDate variables

initial values coming like `{10/1/2013 12:00:00 AM}`

I have converted that using below code to `{10/1/2013 00:00:00}`

```
  sparamFromDate.Value = FromDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

  sparamToDate.Value = toDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

which is giving me expected result for FromDate as : `2013-10-11 00:00:00.000`

But I need a todate in following format how can i convert this in code?

toDate :  `2013-10-11 23:59:59.000`

Comment: is FromDate & toDate having time component?

Comment: What are the initial values of FromDate and toDate variables?

Comment: If you want the very end of the day - don't you actually want 2013-10-11 23:59:59.999 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
toDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59.000");
```

It doesnt matter if toDate is just the date or has a time component - the output will be the same and what you want.

Comment: thanks for simple one but i prefer Add method and timespan cloud be better option :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you are asking for the toDate to be inclusive of all the minutes within that date, regardless of the actual time portion of the calendar time.

The following expression should achieve that result:

```
toDate.Date.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 23, 59, 59, 999)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.nnn");
```

Wal's answer is actually easier.

You should also use the InvariantCulture to perform the `ToString()` operation, as you may end up with something other than ":" or "-" as date and time field separators. Which will likely confuse your database engine.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the DateTime for the end of a day and then ToString() that, using:

```
toDate.Date.AddDays(1).AddMilliseconds(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
toDate.Value = toDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.nnn");
```